# Particles Speed Up When Recording A Video Using ARVideoKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

We have an ARKit & SceneKit app that records videos using ARVideoKit pod ([link](https://github.com/AFathi/ARVideoKit)). Inside our scene we have a fire particle. Fire is playing at a slow speed. However, when you start recording a video the fire particle speeds up. I can't figure out why the fire particle is speeding up. Please see the video ([here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LBtF7SIVlnVu8eL25cfkwQPrxn-araGw/view?usp=sharing)) to see the issue.

Here's a sample project which you can use to test the issue: [Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N8ZGSNhjESqx5C8tq7QyQgkiKVbA3byl/view?usp=sharing)

I would appreciate if anyone can explain why this is happening.

Edit 1: Below is my ViewController Code

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import SceneKit
import ARVideoKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
  @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
  @IBOutlet weak var photoButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var videoButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var takeVideoButtonPressedLabel: UILabel!

  // ARVideoKit Variables
  var recorder  : RecordAR?
  var takenImage: UIImage?
  var takenVideoAtURL : URL?
  let recordingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "recordingThread", attributes: .concurrent)

  var arTrackingConfig = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneView.delegate = self
    sceneView.scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/fire.scn")!
    self.resetTracking()
  }

  func resetTracking() {
    arTrackingConfig = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    arTrackingConfig.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
    sceneView.session.run(arTrackingConfig, options: [.resetTracking,
                                                      .removeExistingAnchors])
  }
}

// MARK: - ARVideoKit Implementation
extension ViewController {
  @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Do Nothing
  }

  @IBAction func takeVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
    setupCamera()
    startRecording()
  }

  func setupCamera() {
    recorder = RecordAR(ARSceneKit: sceneView)
    recorder?.prepare(arTrackingConfig)
  }

  func startRecording() {
    takeVideoButtonPressedLabel.isHidden = false
    recordingQueue.async {
      self.recorder?.record(forDuration: 5) { path in
        self.takenVideoAtURL = path
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.takeVideoButtonPressedLabel.isHidden = true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit 2: Added sample project for testing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While getting the image from SCNRenderer using snapshot method pass 0 as time , this way force rendering will not happen and animations will be smoother. In your case particles will not speed up